# How to integrate checkboxes with jquery to a custom html?

Tags: jquery

I've a situation where i should integrate the check boxes with custom html and also in turn i need all the functions of normal checkbox.

Can you guide me how to do that? I'm new to jquery..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have following structure and when `<a>` is clicked changed the checkbox value using JavaScript. add the image and text to the span.

```
<span>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chbox">
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd ignore the html checkbox altogether for this design. I'd build a graphics element (the blue overlay) which becomes visible when you click the image, and invisible if clicked again. For input, in every div like this, you should put an `<input type="hidden" value="0">`, and with jQuery set the relevant input's value to `1` when the overlay is on, and to `0` again when it's off.

Let me know on which part exactly you're having a problem, I'll try to elaborate.
Hope it helps.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FAfJ/1/)

Comment: I thought of checkboxes because whenever i click invite , each div should have a userid which i thought that can put as a value for checkbox with the same name and when i post them i can get a array of checked checkboxes value.. I need in help in having a checkbox and then linking them with the html i have(so when i select this image the checkbox should be checked and vice versa)t

Comment: added a jsFiddle with an example to the answer